# non-Controller SpringBoot exception interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-integration

I have a spring boot microservice with no controller endpoints.  It operates entirely on a workflow using `inbound-channel-adapter` to query databases and perform some Service action when necessary.

I'd like to intercept all exceptions and judiciously send an alert to the appropriate parties when appropriate.

`@ControllerAdvice doesn't cut it, because there are no controllers.

Any recommendations on how to trap exceptions via an ExceptionHandler or Filter or other means? 
 Our app uses a org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler to log exceptions, extending that could be an option.  I'd prefer not to have all my services extend a single base class that defines an `@ExceptionHandler`.

What is the "spring way" to trap exceptions from workflow channels and send notifications (email/slack/otherwise) to the appropriate user?

Comment: It's AOP here's an [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop/aspectj-afterthrowing-annotation-example/)

Comment: That is why Spring Integration (what you are using) has an error-channel. None of the solutions you are thinking of (controller advice, exception handler etc.) will work as those are for http requests. You are using Spring Integration and use the appropriate means for that library (which are explained in the documentatin).

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin points in his comment, an `errorChannel` approach is used Spring Integration to handle exceptions in the flow. See `error-channel` option on that `inbound-channel-adapter`. It is `errorChannel` by default and it has indeed a `LoggingHandler` as a subscriber. You can stay with that global `errorChannel` as is and just have your own `service-activator` as a subscriber. Or you can configure your own, flow-specific error channel and its subscriber.

See more in documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/error-handling.html#error-handling

Comment: Thank you.  I simply added a `@Service` class with a `@ServiceActivator` method specifying the input channel as the error channel. I did not specify an output channel and had a void for the return value.  This will call my handler first, but then still call the default errorChannels LoggingHandler, which is perfect for my implementation.